# Deleting QCamera crashes program

Tags: c++, macos, qt, camera, crash

I'm using QT and the QCamera object to display a video feed from a camera in a dialog. My code is as follows;

**cameratestdialog.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CameraTestDialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="CameraTestDialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QCameraViewfinder" name="viewfinder" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>281</width>
     <height>201</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QCameraViewfinder</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qcameraviewfinder.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**cameratestdialog.h**

```
#ifndef CAMERATESTDIALOG_H
#define CAMERATESTDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QCamera>

namespace Ui {
class CameraTestDialog;
}

class CameraTestDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CameraTestDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CameraTestDialog();

private:
    Ui::CameraTestDialog *ui;

    QCamera *camera;
};



#endif // CAMERATESTDIALOG_H
```

**cameratestdialog.cpp**

```
#include "cameratestdialog.h"
#include "ui_cameratestdialog.h"

#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QDebug>

CameraTestDialog::CameraTestDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CameraTestDialog),
    camera(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    delete camera;

    camera = new QCamera;
    camera->setViewfinder(ui->viewfinder);
    camera->start();
}

CameraTestDialog::~CameraTestDialog()
{
    qDebug() << "Stopping Camera";
    camera->stop();
    camera->unload();
    //delete camera;
    delete ui;
}
```

In the destructor in `cameratestdialog.cpp`, you can see I've commented out the line to delete the camera. When I run the program like this it works fine (I've tried release and debug modes), I can show and close the dialog as many times as I want without crashes. When I uncomment this line, the program unexpectedly crashes when the destructor is called.

I'm launching the dialog with

```
CameraTestDialog *dlg = new CameraTestDialog();
dlg->show();
```

I'm happy to leave the `delete camera` line commented so my program runs, but doesn't that mean I'm leaking memory every time the dialog is closed? What is the correct way to stop and delete a QCamera object?

I'm running on a 2012 era Mac Book Air under Mavericks, using QT Creator 2.8.1.

---

**EDIT:**

I don't have a debugger installed, so I don't have any more information available at this point about the nature of the crash.

I suspected that the `camera->stop()` and `camera->unload()` calls were behaving asynchronously, and therefore the camera was being deleted before it was actually stopped. To test this, I added while loops that check the camera's state, and block until the camera is confirmed to be stopped, and unloaded. I discovered that these functions are actually synchronous and still had the same symptoms (crashing some time after the delete is called).

---

**EDIT 2:**

I tried changing the references to camera to stack-based, rather than `new`-based, and removed the delete line. After doing this, the program crashes during the constructor, before the dialog is shown.

---

**EDIT 3:**

I've just confirmed that this program does not crash for me on Windows 7, so I'm assuming this a low-level bug in the QT Implementation of QCamera on OSX computers. I will try and raise a bug with the QT project.

Comment: Try to call `delete camera;` after calling `delete ui;`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it and it has the same symptoms (crashes during the destructor). I also tried changing the delete line to `camera->deleteLater()` and got the same result.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on here, but you can try `camera = new QCamera(this)`. This'll make the camera a child of your dialog class. It should be deleted automatically when the dialog is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexP. I tried that and it has the same effect.

Comment: This probably doesn't affect your program, but in your constructor, what's the reason for setting *camera* to 0, deleting *camera* (which is a null pointer), and then initializing *camera*?

Comment: I initialized the camera like that because that's what the QCamera sample project does (I copied their code and removed stuff to get a simple test case). Not sure why they do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, I've just determined that this is indeed some sort of asynchronous problem on OSX. When I allow the dialog to process events for at least 19ms before deleting the camera object, the program does not crash. This suggests to me that it takes a while for the OSX `QCamera` implementation to fully shut down / disconnect from hardware somewhere.

```
CameraTestDialog::~CameraTestDialog()
{
    qDebug() << "Stopping Camera";
    camera->stop();
    camera->unload();

    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(19);
    while(QTime::currentTime() < dieTime) {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
    }

    delete camera;

    delete ui;
}
```

Note that the dialog needs to process events during this waiting period, simply printing some text to the screen causes it to still crash. Also, any less than 19ms causes it to still crash.

Obviously this is a hack solution, so <del>I'm going to submit a bug to the QT project</del> I have submitted [QTBUG-37109](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37109) to the Qt Project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that QCamera seem to run in a Thread. Deleting it "too early" results in a QMutuex error on Windows. Therefore, the solution is `camera->stop();` instead of `camera->unload();`

And finally and most important: Instead of `delete camera` use

```
camera->deleteLater();
```